# How to change video status to set to start point, while accordion hidden?

Tags: html, video

I have a accordion with 4 titles, each titles have one video. while user click on the title, the content will slideup, so it will hidden. while the video player with accordion slide, the user can change in to next slide, but in case the user come back to previous one, the video is 'on' and that in playing state.

what is need is, while accordion slideup, the video has to stop and set to back in the start point of the video, every time the user click, then only it need to play. in case if the slide is hidden, video has top and set to back in the start point.

i found a answer to set back to currentTime to 0...is that correct way? any one help me to showing correct way to archive this?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

it's works for me:

```
videos.each(function (n,v) {
 v.pause(); v.currentTime = 0;
} )
```